# Data not showing up in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

```
class TableController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var ListTable: UITableView!

    var list: [Dictionary<String, String>] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let ListTable = UITableView(frame: view.bounds)
        self.ListTable = ListTable

        ListTable.dataSource = self
        ListTable.delegate = self

        initList()
    }


    func initList() {
          // get list from firebase
            self.ListTable.reloadData()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return list.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let item = self.list[indexPath.row]
        let cellIdentifier = "ListCell"

        let cell = CustomCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)

        cell.foodLabel?.text = item["Banana"]

        return cell
    }
}

extension QueueController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

}
```

CustomCell class:

```
import UIKit

class CustomCell: UITableViewCell
{

    @IBOutlet weak var foodLabel: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib()
    {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }
}
```

My data from firebase loads properly. On storyboard I have a normal view controller with a UITableView embedded inside of it. That table view is liked to my IBOutlet for my ListTable. In the table there is a cell with 3 labels. That cell has the identifier `ListCell` and it's class is `CustomCell`.

Edit: There is no error but my data isn't showing up.

Comment: what does the code that loads the model (ie `list`) look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your Custom Cell does not dequeue properly. Try this one

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cellIdentifier = "ListCell"
        var cell : ListCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier) as! ListCell?
        if (cell == nil) {

            cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ListCell", owner: nil, options: nil)?[0] as? ListCell
        }


        cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        cell?.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

        return cell!
    }
```

Comment: By `ListCell` do you mean `CustomCell`? Or are you implying I need to create a new cell type?

Comment: Yes ListCell mean your CustomCell.

Comment: I have no nib named "List Cell", how can I create a nib? Or does it automatically create? I tried your code and it did not work

Comment: Please show me how did you add UITableViewCell in Storyboard.

Comment: Here this is a tutorial of creating a CustomCell. Please look http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/
and after that you still have a issue please let me know.

Comment: On my UITableView I added a prototype cell and gave it the class `CustomCell`, then I made it's reuse identifier `List Cell`

Comment: Then please remove these lines from viewDidLoad method let ListTable = UITableView(frame: view.bounds)
        self.ListTable = ListTable
and try once again.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try registering your cell in `viewDidLoad`

```
ListTable.register(UINib(nibName: "CustomCell", bundle: Bundle.main), forCellReuseIdentifier: "ListCell") //this is assuming that your nib is named "CustomCell"
```

Also, for the record, you should follow camel-case conventions and name your UITableView `listTable`

Comment: How can I create a nib named CustomCell? Where should this file live and does it need `foodLabel` in it?

Answer (score 0):

You did never add the TableView to your view... (or part go the code is missing )